# Bidirectional addition constraint

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families

A [recent question](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/ob0a1a/type_level_concat_with_good_inference/) on Reddit led to discussion of how one might produce a constraint function

```
type AddUp :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat -> Constraint

-- given
data Nat = Z | S Nat
type family m + n where
  'Z + n = n
  'S m + n = 'S (m + n)
```

such that

1. `AddUp m n o` means that `m + n = o`.
2. Any available type information about `m`, `n`, and/or `o` will flow to the others to the greatest extent possible.

The tricky part is #2, and the trickiest part of that is that if we know, for example, that `m ~ 'S x` and `n ~ 'S ('S y)`, then we should infer from `AddUp m n o` that `o ~ 'S ('S ('S z))` for some `z`.

It's quite easy to do this using incoherent instances, as `/u/Tarmen` showed:

```
class AddUp m n o
instance {-# INCOHERENT #-} n ~ o => AddUp 'Z n o
instance {-# INCOHERENT #-} m ~ o => AddUp m 'Z o
instance {-# INCOHERENT #-} (o ~ 'S po, AddUp m n po) => AddUp ('S m) n o
instance {-# INCOHERENT #-} (o ~ 'S po, AddUp m n po) => AddUp m ('S n) o
instance {-# INCOHERENT #-} (m ~ 'Z, n ~ 'Z) => AddUp m n 'Z
```

This particular use of incoherent instances is perfectly safe, but incoherent instances are a rather shady language feature in general. Is it possible to avoid them?

Comment: Seems like a great application for a typechecker plugin.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I've never written one of those. What would it do in this case? Would it be appreciably different from the incoherent instances?

Comment: A plugin, not living inside the Haskell theory but in the metatheory, is able to observe the difference between a (type) constructor application and other type-level terms, so you can just write an ordinary recursive function that reduces `AddUp` constraints in the way you want. That's my answer to "what would it do". I don't know how to answer "would it be appreciably different from incoherent instances". My understanding is that the goal is to replicate the behavior of the incoherent instances you've shown here; so what does "appreciably different" mean?

Comment: @DanielWagner, what I mean is that `INCOHERENT` is already an "escape hatch" from the usual theory. I figure you might as well use it unless a plugin will allow more programs to be typed, give better error messages, or offer better performance.

Comment: @DanielWagner, ah, I guess a plugin could get you evidence, rather than just inference, quickly. And probably toss in the fundeps.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we can do it! The trick is to produce a bunch of equality constraints by matching on `m` and `n` in all the ways we can, in parallel. Here's a naive first attempt:

```hs
type AddUp m n o = (Bar m n o, Bar n m o, Baz m n o)

type family Bar m n o where
  Bar 'Z n o = n ~ o
  Bar ('S m) n o = (o ~ 'S (Pred o), AddUp m n (Pred o))

type family Baz m n o :: Constraint where
  Baz m n 'Z = (m ~ 'Z, n ~ 'Z)
  Baz _ _ _ = ()

type family Pred n where
  Pred ('S n) = n
```

This actually works, but it has a big problem: it takes exponential (or worse) time and space to compile! What's the problem? Consider `AddUp ('S m) ('S n) o`, and let's ignore `Baz` for now. This produces `Bar ('S m) ('S n) o` and `Bar ('S n) ('S m) o`. The first reduces to `(o ~ S (Pred o), AddUp m (S n) (Pred o))` while the second reduces to `(o ~ S (Pred o), AddUp n (S m) (Pred o))`. Expanding `AddUp`, we see that one produces, among other things, `Bar (S n) m (Pred o)`, while the other produces, among other things, `Bar (S m) n (Pred o)`. When these, in turn, reduce, they produce (among other things), `AddUp n m (Pred o)` and `AddUp m n (Pred o)`, which are equivalent.

How can we fix this? We need to break up `Bar` into two type families, the second of which is more restricted in what it matches on.

```hs
type AddUp m n o = (Bar m n o, Barf n m o, Baz m n o)

type family Bar m n o where
  Bar 'Z n o = n ~ o
  Bar ('S m) n o = (o ~ 'S (Pred o), AddUp m n (Pred o))
  
-- A version of Bar that refrains from matching on the second argument.
-- This is necessary to avoid exponential constraint size.
type family Barf m n o where
  Barf 'Z n o = n ~ o
  Barf ('S m) n o = (o ~ 'S (Pred o), Barf m n (Pred o), Baz m n (Pred o))

-- These are the same

type family Baz m n o :: Constraint where
  Baz m n 'Z = (m ~ 'Z, n ~ 'Z)
  Baz _ _ _ = ()

type family Pred n where
  Pred ('S n) = n
```

I believe this version requires only polynomial time (at least quadratic), rather than exponential. Or maybe reduces it by an exponential order from something even worse, once all the unification work and such is accounted for. In practice, it's substantially slower than the version using incoherent instances, but far, far faster than the naive version.

Comment: Aw come on, addition in _O_ (exp(exp _ℓ_)) is not too bad...